# Converting trilateration points to CRS.Simple leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, android, leaflet, indoor-positioning-system

I'm developing an indoor positioning mobile application and i'm successfully able to achieve this using trilateration method.The next step required is representing the tritleration point (User's indoor location) on an indoor map. 
I've been searching the web and luckily i've found Leaflet.js and i followed this tutorial on Non-Geographic maps: [Leaflet.js Tutorial](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html).The question here is how can i convert my indoor coordinates i got from the trilateration technique to Co-ordinate Reference System (CRS.simple used in leaflet.js),plus how can i get my conversion accurate on my indoor map as in how can i fit the points only inside the indoor area drawn on the map not outside the bounds of my hall for example. Here is a screenshot of my floorplan im working on.[image: My indoorMap using Leaflet.js]

Comment: It is totally up to you to specify the size of your floor plan, so that it matches the results of your trilateration. Beyond the Leaflet tutorial, you have plenty resources, including here on SO, about how to specify the size of your floorplan. Without further technical details of your plan and trilateration results, it is hard to provide you with help.

Comment: @ghybs is that a practical way? i mean can i just resize my floor plan and use measurements as you stated to get an accurate indoor navigation application? What about georeferencing the floor plan? QGIS? i have searched a lot to avoid just using an image rather than overlying an image.

Comment: As stated above, without further details of your situation, you will understand that it is difficult to provide relevant answers. Georeferencing might be interesting, provided that your positioning also gives absolute coordinates.